Ping only works after arping the destination address
I have a macOS vm bridging to the mac's NIC, the openwrt router has a subnet of 192.168.54.0/24 and the vm's address is 192.168.54.15. I have a standalone kubernetes cluster on the VM with Pod cidr 192.168.254.0/28 and cilium CNI.
VM Interfaces:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d2:ce:ba:d6:d3:97 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.54.15/24 metric 1024 brd 192.168.54.255 scope global enp0s1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: cilium_net@cilium_host: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 96:dd:fe:78:83:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: cilium_host@cilium_net: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8e:66:4c:b5:d5:e8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.254.13/32 scope global cilium_host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: lxc_health@if5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5e:2e:e6:d1:d9:ec brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
10: lxca0a4b8f7dc6d@if9: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 32:c3:c3:a7:16:a4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns cni-57052f12-1959-6b0e-4271-6b05c21bef6c

OpenWrt routes:
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  src 192.168.1.2 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 scope link  src 192.168.1.2 
192.168.54.0/24 dev br-lan scope link  src 192.168.54.1 
192.168.254.0/28 via 192.168.54.15 dev br-lan

OpenWrt firewall:
root@GL-MT3000:~# nft list ruleset
table ip main {
    chain postrouting {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        oif "eth0" masquerade
    }
}

I cannot ping the cilium_host address on the openwrt router:
root@GL-MT3000:~# ping 192.168.254.13
PING 192.168.254.13 (192.168.254.13): 56 data bytes
^C
--- 192.168.254.13 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss

But if I use arping first:
root@GL-MT3000:~# arping 192.168.254.13
ARPING 192.168.254.13 from 192.168.54.1 br-lan
Unicast reply from 192.168.254.13 [C8:89:F3:AE:C9:7C]  45.140ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.254.13 [C8:89:F3:AE:C9:7C]  3.995ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.254.13 [C8:89:F3:AE:C9:7C]  93.833ms

The ping then works:
root@GL-MT3000:~# ping 192.168.254.13
PING 192.168.254.13 (192.168.254.13): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.254.13: seq=0 ttl=64 time=2.993 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.254.13: seq=1 ttl=64 time=84.748 ms
^C
--- 192.168.254.13 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 2.993/43.870/84.748 ms

But there's still no arp entry for 192.168.254.13:
root@GL-MT3000:~# ip nei
192.168.1.40 dev eth0  used 0/0/0 probes 6 FAILED
192.168.54.2 dev br-lan  used 0/0/0 probes 6 FAILED
192.168.1.1 dev eth0 lladdr 10:47:e7:3a:59:a8 ref 1 used 0/0/0 probes 1 REACHABLE
192.168.54.164 dev br-lan  used 0/0/0 probes 6 FAILED
192.168.1.8 dev eth0  used 0/0/0 probes 6 FAILED
192.168.54.3 dev br-lan lladdr ec:74:8c:c2:a8:5d ref 1 used 0/0/0 probes 1 REACHABLE
192.168.1.101 dev eth0  used 0/0/0 probes 6 FAILED
192.168.1.155 dev eth0  used 0/0/0 probes 6 FAILED
192.168.1.139 dev eth0  used 0/0/0 probes 6 FAILED
192.168.1.7 dev eth0  used 0/0/0 probes 6 FAILED
192.168.1.100 dev eth0  used 0/0/0 probes 6 FAILED
192.168.1.14 dev eth0  used 0/0/0 probes 6 FAILED
192.168.1.21 dev eth0  used 0/0/0 probes 6 FAILED
192.168.54.6 dev br-lan lladdr 96:89:69:ca:08:66 ref 1 used 0/0/0 probes 1 REACHABLE
192.168.54.68 dev br-lan lladdr c8:89:f3:ae:c9:7c used 0/0/0 probes 6 STALE
192.168.1.106 dev eth0  used 0/0/0 probes 6 FAILED
192.168.1.5 dev eth0  used 0/0/0 probes 6 FAILED
192.168.54.238 dev br-lan  used 0/0/0 probes 6 FAILED
192.168.54.15 dev br-lan lladdr c8:89:f3:ae:c9:7c used 0/0/0 probes 1 STALE
192.168.1.4 dev eth0  used 0/0/0 probes 6 FAILED
192.168.1.159 dev eth0  used 0/0/0 probes 6 FAILED
192.168.1.11 dev eth0  used 0/0/0 probes 6 FAILED
192.168.54.4 dev br-lan lladdr 70:31:7f:02:9b:18 ref 1 used 0/0/0 probes 1 REACHABLE
192.168.1.104 dev eth0  used 0/0/0 probes 6 FAILED
192.168.1.3 dev eth0 lladdr 3c:7c:3f:d8:94:d8 used 0/0/0 probes 6 STALE
192.168.1.10 dev eth0  used 0/0/0 probes 6 FAILED
192.168.54.5 dev br-lan lladdr c8:89:f3:ae:c9:7c ref 1 used 0/0/0 probes 1 REACHABLE
192.168.54.134 dev br-lan lladdr 78:df:72:33:42:38 ref 1 used 0/0/0 probes 1 REACHABLE
192.168.1.9 dev eth0  used 0/0/0 probes 6 FAILED
fe80::1 dev eth0 lladdr 10:47:e7:3a:59:a8 router used 0/0/0 probes 0 STALE

Questions:

Why there's no ARP entry in the table?
Why the ping does not work initially despite I have a route to it and how to fix it?


What device is C8:89:F3:AE:C9:7C? Is 192.168.254.0/28 supposed to be routed through br-lan? Actually, how is it routed through br-lan when your interface list doesn't have such an interface?

@grawity It vm's interface and it's bridged to the host mac's wireless interface. 192.168.254.0/28 is on another vm's interface and ip forward is enabled.

That doesn't really clarify things. In your post, you have "OpenWrt routes" showing eth0 and br-lan interfaces, but then you have "OpenWrt interfaces" showing enp0s1 and neither eth0 nor br-lan are shown. Do both outputs actually come from the same device with the same OpenWrt?

@grawity Sorry, my bad, it should be vm's interface list and C8:89:F3:AE:C9:7C is host Mac's wireless interface MAC. Hope it makes sense now.
